# Trunk lid will not open

Tags: dodge, trunk, charger

I think something got jammed in my 2006 dodge charger trunk. The key wont open it and neither does the button. Was loading my trunk and guess I didn't notice something was in the way when I closed the trunk. Now it wont open. How can I get my trunk lid open?

Comment: Do the rear seats fold down? If you can see if you can pull the latch from the inside. or you might be able to see what's jammed. Another suggestion would be that if there's too much pressure from the stuff in the trunk it'll strain against the latch. Try pushing down on the lid and actuating the latch.

Comment: I would consider contacting Dodge... Not a local dealer, but the headquarters. Let me/us know how that turns out.

Comment: contact your local dealer as they most likely has solved this problem multiple times before,you might also ask at your local service station on what to do.
(sorry for my bad english spelling).